# Swagger : Custom code generator, custom classes/interfaces names and new folders/files

Tags: java, osgi, swagger, swagger-codegen

I developed a custom code generator following the guidelines shared on the wiki. I managed to 
define one that extends AbstractJavaJAXRSServerCodegen abstract class. I didn't figure out how to:

- define new folders and files inside them, in a programatic way (since I'm developing on an OSGi runtime, I was wondering if I could generate dynamically a ${component}.xml for each yaml file and ). I managed to create an OSGI-INF folder with writeOptional... method. Now I need to put as many .xml files as yaml files inside this folder.
- define my own policy for classes and interfaces names. My urgent need is to prefix interfaces with a **I** character to be compliant with code styling guidelines

Is it possibile ? I suppose I should work on my generator java class but I can't find any hint to do it. Also I didn't find exact references inside parent classes of my generator

Comment: Your `${component}.xml` files are just empty files?

Comment: My xml files are not empty, they contain OSGi related instructions. My problem is not with the content of them, instead with:
1) dynamic generation of more than one file: I discovered, after digging in the examples on github, that there's a wirteOptional method that can be used to generate files. But i don't understand how to do this operation for each yaml file... How can I cycle on my yaml files from the context of my custom generator without knowing first all the yaml files. Are there hidden methods to do so?
2) how to define my completely custom folders structure